# How to grep files from specific date to EOF awk

Tags: bash, date, awk, grep, format

I have a little problem with printing data from file from date to end of file, namely, I have file:

```
2016/08/10-12:45:14.970000 <some_data> <some_data> ...
2016/08/10-12:45:15.970000 <some_data> <some_data> ...
2016/08/10-12:45:18.970000 <some_data> <some_data> ...
2016/08/10-12:45:19.970000 <some_data> <some_data> ...
```

And this file has hundreds lines.

And I have to print file from one point in the time to end of file but I don't know precise time when row in logfile appeared.

And I need to print data from date `2016/08/10-12:45:16`to end of file, I want to receive file looks like that:

```
2016/08/10-12:45:18.970000 
2016/08/10-12:45:19.970000
```

OK if I know specific date from which I want to print data everything is easy

```
awk '/<start_time>/,/<end/'
awk '/2016\/08\/10-12:45:18/,/<end/'
```

But if I don't know specific date, I know only approximate date `2016/08/10-12:45:16` it's harder.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: escape the slashes with a backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can benefit from the fact that the time format you are using supports alphanumerical comparison. With awk the command can look like this:

```
awk -v start='2016/08/10-12:45:16' '$1>=start'  file
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, This is exactly what I looked for. :)

Comment: @DamianSilkowski what does your log file look like when DST ends? Does it go, for example, from `2016/11/06-01:59:59` to `2016/11/06-01:00:00`? If so what should the script output if you were searching for the entries from `2016/11/06-01:30:00` on? Should it include the `2016/11/06-01:00:00` that ocurred when DST ended AFTER your target timestamp was passed in your log file? You'll want to use `$1>=start{f=1} f`, if you want from timestamp to end of file as you said in your question. There's still a grey area in there that'd require `mktime()` to address but it's probably not really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mktime` function of `awk` to check for time:

```
awk -v TIME="2016/08/10-12:45:16" '
    BEGIN{
       gsub("[/:-]"," ",TIME)
       reftime=mktime(TIME)
    }
    {
      t=$1
      sub("[0-9]*$","",t)
      gsub("[/:-]"," ",t)
      if(mktime(t)>reftime) 
          print
    }' file
```

This script take your reference time and convert it into number and then compare it to time found in the file.

Note the `sub` and `gsub` are only to convert your specific time format to the time format understood by `awk`.

Comment: It working, in every case. But i'm looking something less complex. If I will not find I'll use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this simply with `awk`:

```
awk '{m = "2016/08/10-12:45:18"} $0 ~ m,0 {print}' file
```

If you weren't sure exactly the time or date you could do:

```
awk '{m = "2016/08/10-12:45:1[6-8]"} $0 ~ m,0 {print}' file
```

This should print from your specified date and time around 12:45 +16-18 seconds to the files end. The character class `[6-8]` treats the seconds as a range from the original time `12:45:1...`

**Output:**

```
2016/08/10-12:45:18.970000 somedata 3
2016/08/10-12:45:19.970000 somedata 4
```

Comment: Ok but if I set `m = 2016/08/10-12:45:18` it returns me nothing

Comment: It worked fine for me, so maybe check the command again, or provide more information about the version of `awk` you use, and *real* input data. If your input file does not match precisely what is in your question then that could explain it. I've tried the command in Linux, and OS X, both gave the correct output.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry if I set `m = 2016/08/10-12:45:16` it returns me nothing. Check it. I appreciate your effort, but i had a mistake in my previous comment.

Comment: When you don't know the precise time then you should use the second example which allows a range between +16-18 seconds: `m = "2016/08/10-12:45:1[6-8]"`. The time you've specified doesn't exist in the file, so you'll need to use an approximate time range.

Comment: Yup, but like I mentioned file (logfile) has hundreds lines and the period of time includes in this log is ~20min and I need data from one point in the time (when i do some changes in configuration) to end of this file and I'm not sure when new row in logifle appeared, I know only the time of changes.

Comment: I don't know how you expect any tool to "guess" what time the output should begin.

Comment: Not "guess", only print all rows which are younger than date what I give.